# Suppress page header on first page of report footer crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to suppress the page header on page one of report footer.

So i have multiple  report footer each one on a new page So I want to make the first report footer without page header .

"not Onlastrecord" make page header appear on each page of my report footer

```
Page 1           Page 2        ......   Page n       page n+1  ***page***      page          page
|Page Header     |Page Header          |Page Header  |Details  |report Footer  |Page Header  |Page Header
                                                                               |report Footer|report Footer
```

I want the first report Footer to not have Page Header.
Can someone help please?

Comment: Does your report footer occupy more than one page?

Comment: yes , what user enter will appear in report footer

Answer (score 0):

Would it be enough to just put a page break in report footer? ("new page before" in section expert).

If not...

I'm not sure if it will work and i can't test it know, but it may at least lead you to new resources:

1. Create a formula. Let's call it {@Init}. Its content:

   ```
   shared numbervar pageNumberOfLastRecord := 0
   ```
2. Put that formula in report header and suppress it.
3. Create another formula. Let's call it {@Setter}. Its content:

   ```
   shared numbervar pageNumberOfLastRecord;
   if onlastrecord then pageNumberOfLastRecord := pageNumber;
   ```
4. Put that formula in details section.
5. Use this formula to suppress page footer:

   ```
   shared numbervar pageNumberOfLastRecord;
   pageNumber = pageNumberOfLastRecord
   ```